# Remapping <ESC> breaks <S-TAB> mapping in vim

Tags: vim

I had the following mapping on my vimrc

```
nnoremap <TAB> gt
nnoremap <S-TAB> gT
```

Then I mapped ESC to clear highlights as:

```
noremap <silent> <ESC> :noh<return>
```

And then `<S-TAB>` wont work anymore. If I remove `<silent>` from `<ESC>` mapping I see `:noh` when I press `<S-TAB>`. I don't know if `<S-TAB>` and `<ESC>` has something in common. I'm on Linux, using vim on gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in assuming that `<S-TAB>` and `<ESC>` have something in common. `S-TAB` is an escape-prefixed keycode.

The `ESC` keycode is `^[`, while `S-TAB` is `^[[Z`. You can see the first part of the `S-TAB` key code matching the `ESC` keycode.

See a [full table of combinations here](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Keycodes#special-keys).

So you just **can't** remap the escape key while also remapping one of the key codes including it. Either pick a different key to clear highlights or a different way of switching tabs.